# In Swift, what's the cleanest way to get the last two items in an Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, slice

Is there a cleaner way to get the last two items of an array in Swift? In general, I try to avoid this approach since it's so easy to be off-by-one with the indexes. (Using Swift 1.2 for this example.)

```
// Swift -- slices are kind of a hassle?
let oneArray = ["uno"]
let twoArray = ["uno", "dos"]
let threeArray = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]

func getLastTwo(array: [String]) -> [String] {
    if array.count <= 1 {
        return array
    } else {
        let slice: ArraySlice<String> = array[array.endIndex-2..<array.endIndex]
        var lastTwo: Array<String> = Array(slice)
        return lastTwo
    }
}

getLastTwo(oneArray)   // ["uno"]
getLastTwo(twoArray)   // ["uno", "dos"]
getLastTwo(threeArray) // ["dos", "tres"]
```

I was hoping for something closer to Python's convenience.

```
## Python -- very convenient slices
myList = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]
print myList[-2:] # ["dos", "tres"]
```

Comment: This QA and the excellent answer might be useful for anyone googling here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312252

Answer (score 100, accepted):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you may choose one of the following patterns in order to get a new array from the last two elements of an array.

---

### #1. Using Array's `suffix(_:)`

With Swift, objects that conform to `Collection` protocol have a `suffix(_:)` method. Array's [`suffix(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687909-suffix) has the following declaration:

```
func suffix(_ maxLength: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element>
```

> Returns a subsequence, up to the given maximum length, containing the final elements of the collection.

*Usage:*

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let arraySlice = array.suffix(2)
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints: [3, 4]
```

---

### #2. Using `Array`'s `subscript(_:)`

As an alternative to `suffix(_:)` method, you may use `Array`'s [`subscript(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2944258-subscript) subscript:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let range = array.index(array.endIndex, offsetBy: -2) ..< array.endIndex
//let range = array.index(array.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)... // also works
let arraySlice = array[range]
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints: [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 56):

> `myList[-2:]`

Yes, I have an enhancement request filed asking for negative index notation, and I suggest you file one too.

However, you shouldn't make this harder on yourself than you have to. The built-in global `suffix` function does exactly what you're after:

```
let oneArray = ["uno"]
let twoArray = ["uno", "dos"]
let threeArray = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]

let arr1 = oneArray.suffix(2) // ["uno"]
let arr2 = twoArray.suffix(2) // ["uno", "dos"]
let arr3 = threeArray.suffix(2) // ["dos", "tres"]
```

The result is a slice, but you can coerce it to an Array if you need to.

Comment: In Swift 2.0 `suffix(MyCoolArray, 3)` becomes `MyCoolArray.suffix(3)`
Thought I'd share so no one else pulls as much hair out as I did

Comment: what about **dropFirst:(length-2)**

Answer (score 13):

in **swift 5** you can use suffix for get objects from the last and use prefix for get objects from the first, here is an example:

```
let exampleArray = ["first text", "second text", "third text"]

let arr1 = exampleArray.suffix(2) // ["second text", "third text"]
let arr2 = exampleArray.prefix(2) // ["first text", "second text"]
```

The result is a slice, but you can coerce it to an Array if you need to.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 2, you can extend `CollectionType`. Here's an example (borrowing from Rob Napier's answer):

```
extension CollectionType {
    func last(count:Int) -> [Self.Generator.Element] {
        let selfCount = self.count as! Int
        if selfCount <= count - 1 {
            return Array(self)
        } else {
            return Array(self.reverse()[0...count - 1].reverse())
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it on any `CollectionType`. Here's `Array`:

```
let array = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]
print(array.last(2)) // [dos, tres]
```

Here's `CharacterView`:

```
let string = "looking"
print(string.characters.last(4)) // [k, i, n, g]
```

(Note that my example returns an Array in all cases, not the original collection type.)

Comment: "my example returns an Array in all cases" That seems perfectly reasonable, though; `map` behaves the same way, IIRC. You can always cast back to whatever-it-is if desired.

Answer (score 3):

More generic answer ...

```
let a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let a2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

func getLast<T>(array: [T], count: Int) -> [T] {
  if count >= array.count {
    return array
  }
  let first = array.count - count
  return Array(array[first..<first+count])
}

getLast(a1, count: 2) // [4, 5]
getLast(a2, count: 3) // ["3", "4", "5"]
```

Answer (score 3):

> the last two items of an array in Swift

EDIT: first checks that myArray.count >= 2

```
let myArray2:Array? = myArray.count >= 2 ? [myArray[myArray.count-2], myArray[myArray.count-1]] : nil
```

Here it is wrapped in a function which takes the array and either returns an array containing the last two or else returns nil if the passed array does not contain at least two items.

```
func getLastTwo(myArray:[String]) -> [String]? {
        return myArray.count >= 2 ? [myArray[myArray.count-2], myArray[myArray.count-1]] : nil
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not safe if the array is not guaranteed to have at least two items in it.

Answer (score 3):

```
let items = [0, 2, 5, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10]
let count = items.count
let last2 = items[count - 2 ..< count] // [9, 10]
```

Comment: i think it will cause crash because no index for item[count]

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it's going to make you that much happier, but the math is certainly simpler:

```
func getLastTwo(array: [String]) -> [String] {
    if array.count <= 1 {
        return array
    } else {
        return array.reverse()[0...1].reverse()
    }
}
```

Note that `reverse()` is lazy, so this isn't particularly expensive.

Answer (score -1):

Swift4 solution:

```
let oneArray = ["uno"]
let twoArray = ["uno", "dos"]
let threeArray = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]

let arr1 = threeArray.suffix(from: threeArray.count-2) // ["dos", "tres"]
```

Other examples to clarify the functionality of Swift's built in function `func suffix(from start: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element>` are...

```
let arr2 = oneArray.suffix(from: 0) // ["uno"]
let arr3 = twoArray.suffix(from: 0) // ["uno", "dos"]
let arr4 = twoArray.suffix(from: 1) // ["dos"]
let arr5 = threeArray.suffix(from: 1) // ["dos", "tres"]
let arr6 = threeArray.suffix(from: 2) // ["tres"]
```