# What type should you use when you want to use index.advanceBy?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexof

I wanted to find some objects near another object in an array. I thought I could write an extension method like this, but I get this error:

```
// Error: Cannot invoke 'advanceBy' with an argument list of type '(Int)'
```

The `Int` type is obviously wrong, but the `indexOf` method takes a `Self.Distance` argument and I'm not sure how to use that as a parameter type.

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    func objectNear(object: Self.Generator.Element, indexModifier: Int) -> Self.Generator.Element? {
        if let index = self.indexOf(object) {
            let newIndex = index.advancedBy(indexModifier) // this doesn't work
            //let newIndex = index.advancedBy(1) // but this this works
            if self.indices.contains(newIndex) {
                return self[newIndex]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

(If there is a more Swifty approach I'd be happy to hear it, but I'd like to understand the above in any case.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CollectionType` has the method

```
public func indexOf(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?
```

and conforms to

```
public protocol Indexable {
    typealias Index : ForwardIndexType
    // ...
}
```

Finally, `ForwardIndexType` has the method

```
public func advancedBy(n: Self.Distance) -> Self
```

Therefore the correct type is `Index.Distance`:

```
func objectNear(object: Self.Generator.Element, indexModifier: Index.Distance) -> Self.Generator.Element? { ... }
```

But note that advancing an index beyond `endIndex` can crash,
e.g. for character collections:

```
let c = "abc".characters
print(c.objectNear("b", indexModifier: 1)) // Optional("c")
print(c.objectNear("b", indexModifier: 2)) // nil
print(c.objectNear("b", indexModifier: 3)) // fatal error: can not increment endIndex
```

A safe variant is:

```
func objectNear(object: Generator.Element, indexModifier: Index.Distance) -> Generator.Element? {
    if let index = indexOf(object) {
        if indexModifier > 0 && index.distanceTo(endIndex) <= indexModifier {
            return nil
        }
        if indexModifier < 0 && startIndex.distanceTo(index) < -indexModifier {
            return nil
        }
        return self[index.advancedBy(indexModifier)]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Alternatively, if you need the method only for collections which
are indexed by an `Int` (such as `Array`) then you can define

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable, Index == Int {

    func objectNear(object: Generator.Element, indexModifier: Int) -> Generator.Element? {
        if let index = self.indexOf(object) {
            let newIndex = index + indexModifier
            if indices.contains(newIndex) {
                return self[newIndex]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just typing that =] Martin is correct. I recently encountered a similar issue with stride.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Since I am a big fan of [negative indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007643/in-swift-whats-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-last-two-items-in-an-array), how can I get out-of-bounds indexes to return nil [instead of the first element](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ebf1fee6bfbe28db196)? (Limiting by `startIndex` makes `-1` return the first element.)

Comment: @zekel: I have updated the answer with a version that should cover all combinations. There might be a more elegant one, but this is what I have so far.