# What's Swift's "fromAfter" call in array slices?

Tags: swift3, slice

Swift 3 has **upTo** and **through**

which are noninclusive, inclusive respectively

> func prefix(upTo: Int)
>   Returns a subsequence from the start of the collection **up to, but not including**, the specified position.

.

> func prefix(through: Int)
>   Returns a subsequence from the start of the collection **through** the specified position.

for the other end it has **from**

> func suffix(from: Int)
>   Returns a subsequence from the specified position to the end of the collection.

which seems to be inclusive

What's the non-inclusive call at the far end??

```
    // sum the numbers before, and after, an index i...

    let lo = A.prefix(upTo: i).reduce(0,+)    // means noninclusive
    let hi = A.suffix(from: i+1).reduce(0,+)  // 'from' seems to mean inclusive
```

what's the call I don't know? It sucks to have to write from with +1.

Comment: A non-inclusive signature isn't in the Swift Standard Library reference and both the `suffix(_:)` and `suffix(from: )` references show inclusive examples, so it's not available in this version. I also saw no discussion that references a non-inclusive suffix, so it's not likely to be available any time soon.

Comment: Ah - brilliant info.  Maybe should paste it in as a decisive answer, @gelliott181 ?

Comment: I'm an ephemeral swift user so I usually prefer to leave an actual answer to someone who can give details, just as @dfri made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no non-inclusive `suffix` method for for `Collection` types in the stdlib, but for this use case, you can readily implement your own by combining `suffix(from:)` with `dropFirst(_:)` (which, imho, better shows intent than `from: idx+1`), e.g.

```
extension Collection where SubSequence == SubSequence.SubSequence {
    public func suffix(after start: Index) -> SubSequence {
        return suffix(from: start).dropFirst(1)
    }
}
```

Applied to your example (separately sum numbers before and after a given partitioning number (or, index of), not including the partitioning one):

```
/* in this example, invalid indices will yield a full-array sum into
   lo or hi, depending on high or low index out of bounds, respectively */
func splitSum(of arr: [Int], at: Int) -> (Int, Int) {
    guard at < arr.count else { return (arr.reduce(0, +), 0) }
    guard at >= 0 else { return (0, arr.reduce(0, +)) }

    let lo = arr.prefix(upTo: at).reduce(0, +)
    let hi = arr.suffix(after: at).reduce(0, +)

    return (lo, hi)
}

// example usage
let arr = [Int](repeating: 1, count: 10)
print(splitSum(of: arr, at: 4)) // (4, 5)
```

---

Leaving the subject of a non-inclusive `suffix` method, an alternative approach to your split sum calculation would be to use one of [the `split(...)` methods](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/2297966-split) for `Collection` types:

```
func splitSum(of arr: [Int], at: Int) -> (Int, Int) {
    guard at < arr.count else { return (arr.reduce(0, +), 0) }
    guard at >= 0 else { return (0, arr.reduce(0, +)) }

    let sums = arr.enumerated()
        .split (omittingEmptySubsequences: false) { $0.0 == at }
        .map { $0.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.1 } }

    guard let lo = sums.first, let hi = sums.last else { fatalError() }

    return (lo, hi)
}

// example: same as above
```

I believe the `split` version is a bit more verbose, however, and also semantically poorer at showing the intent of the code.

Comment: Spectacular.  I have to admit I don't understand **where SubSequence == SubSequence.SubSequence**, nor could I really find it explained in the doco or any tutorials.  Maybe you could generously add a line explaining it, for mortals reading  ;)  Tak!

Comment: @JoeBlow It's not as tricky as one might think at first glance. The return type of the `suffix(after:)` method is `Self.SubSequence`. Now, for some given sequence, say `seq`, the existing `suffix(from:)` method (which we call in the return clause of our method) returns. itself, an instance of type `Self.SubSequence` (where `Self` is the type of `seq`: some type conforming to `Sequence`). So if the `return` statement would look like `return suffix(from: start)`, we wouldn't need the `where SubSequence == SubSequence.SubSequence` specification, since the type of the `return` clause match ...

Comment: ... the return type we've specified in the `suffix(after:)` method, namely, `Self.SubSequence`. In our case, however, we apply the `dropFirst(_:)` method _upon the `Self.SubSequence` instance returned from the `suffix(from:)` call_. The return type of the `dropFirst(_:)` is, also, `Self.SubSequence`, with `Self` being the type of the caller. Since, in our case, the caller is `Self.SubSequence` (with `Self` being the type of `seq`), the _type_ of the chained call `suffix(from: start).dropFirst(1)` is `Self.SubSequence.SubSequence`. Since the return type of the method is `Self.SubSequence`, ...

Comment: ... we need to ascertain that `Self.SubSequence` is indeed the same type as `Self.SubSequence.SubSequence`, hence the specification `where SubSequence == SubSequence.SubSequence` in the "signature" of the extension. So in the end it simply boils down to ascertaining that we return the correct type as specified by the method signature of `suffix(after:)`. Hope this clears things up!

Comment: That will take some thought  :O

Comment: @JoeBlow Glad I could help! That would be my first one, much obliged, likewise thanks!

Comment: your first one, hard to believe.  thanks again!  BTW i'm still slowly digesting your explanation "It's not as tricky as one might think at first glance..."  :-)

Comment: @JoeBlow feel free to post any additional questions regarding it after you feel done digesting it. We'll simply delete our comments in case this comment tail were to grow. And yes maybe that "not as tricky" was not on target :)