# Get last 10 elements from array : NSMakeRange

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I need to get last 10 elements or min of 10 and array.count. In objective-C I have done it like this :

Objective-C code :

```
NSRange endRange = NSMakeRange(sortedArray.count >= 10 ? sortedArray.count - 10 : 0, MIN(sortedArray.count, 10));
NSArray *lastElements= [sortedArray subarrayWithRange:endRange];
```

In Swift I have done this :

```
let endRange = NSMakeRange(values.count >= 10 ? values.count - 10 : 0, min(values.count , 10) )
```

But don't know how to get the array using this range in swift. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Top Google hit for "swift last elements from array" – The Swift 2/3 code is for example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33279008/1187415 to the duplicate.

Comment: let sortedArray:NSArray = [150,125,115,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,15];
        let endRange = NSMakeRange(sortedArray.count >= 10 ? sortedArray.count - 10 : 0, min(sortedArray.count , 10) ) as NSRange
        let result = sortedArray.subarray(with: endRange)
        print("Results is: \(result)")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Array Instance Method `suffix(_:)`. Note that using suffix you don't need to check your array count. It will take up to 10 elements from the end of your array.

```
let array = Array(1...100)   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]

let lastTenElements = Array(array.suffix(10))   // [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Comment: Your solution is better.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way, and it is working as it should. Just a question will it affect the efficiency if the array is of 10,000

Comment: This is the proper of doing it. You shouldn't worry about efficiency

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by declaring [Range](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/range):

```
let letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"]

let desiredRange = letters.index(letters.endIndex, offsetBy: -10) ..< letters.endIndex

// ["e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"]
let lastTenLetters = (desiredRange.count > letters.count) ? letters : Array(letters[desiredRange])
```

Note that if the desired range's count is more than the main array's count, the last ten elements should be the whole main array.

Although I still agree that [Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44127997/5501940) is the proper one for your case, I would like to mention that the good thing about this solution is that it is applicable for not only last element, to make it clear, consider that you want to get 10 elements after the first one (referring to `letters` array, elements should be *b-k*), by implementing a desired range, you could achieve this, as follows:

```
let letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"]

let desiredRange = letters.index(letters.startIndex, offsetBy: 1) ..< letters.index(letters.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)

// ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
let lastTenLetters = (desiredRange.count > letters.count) ? letters : Array(letters[desiredRange])
```

Comment: this would crash the app if the array has less then 10 elements

Comment: @LeoDabus you are right, I edited it... but I assume that in my code snippet it should be also applicable for not only last elements, please assist. Still think that for last elements case your answer is the proper one, I voted it up :)

Answer (score 0):

var values : NSArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

```
    values = values.reversed() as NSArray

    let tenDigits = values.prefix(10)

    debugPrint(values.count >= 10 ? NSArray(array: (Array(tenDigits))) : min(values.count , 10))
```