# Swift - Leave last X number items in array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have array with 50 items. How to leave in the array only the last 30 items without for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Swift, what's the cleanest way to get the last two items in an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007643/in-swift-whats-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-last-two-items-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ArraySlice`:

```
let lastThirty = array[20...]
```

Note that `lastThirty` is of type `ArraySlice`, so to get it back as an array, you can do:

```
let lastThirtyArray = Array(lastThirty)
```

You can read more about `ArraySlice`s [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice).

Comment: if I have more than 50 items can I use `array[array.count-30...]` ??

Comment: yes you can! You might want to have a check to make sure that your array is longer than 30 before doing the splicing though.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
  print(a1[2...])
```

so you just need the `array[20...]`

or `array.dropfirst(20)`

Comment: `dropFirst(_:)` is preferable, because it gracefully handles going out of bounds

Comment: This will return 30 elements only if the array has exactly 50 elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is collections method suffix

> func suffix(_ maxLength: Int) -> ArraySlice

It will return n elements up to the number of elements in your collection:

```
let input = Array(1...100)
let last30 = input.suffix(30)  // [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```